# Safari Inspect elements on mobile device

Tags: safari

I recently upgraded to latest Safari `14.1.1` and the device inspector dev tools have stopped working. When selecting a target through the Develop menu, the inspector window pops up but is unusable and many of the inspector tabs are disabled. The device I'm inspecting is running latest iOS. Is there some additional security setting I need to enable?

https://webkit.org/web-inspector/enabling-web-inspector/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a bug that affects everyone as far as I’m aware. It has been fixed in [Safari Technology Preview 125](https://developer.apple.com/safari/technology-preview/release-notes/) which should make it into the next release of Safari.

> #### Release 125
>
> ##### Web Inspector
>
> - Remote Inspection
>
>   - Fixed an issue that prevented remotely inspecting iOS and iPadOS devices